# Android database rawQuery: strange Cursor behaviour

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I need to check tables in my database before upgrade it.

I overrode `SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVer, int newVer)` in my own DatabaseHelper to do the work when database version increase.

I use this query on sqlite_master table to get table names:`select * from sqlite_master` but cursor seems empty even if `cursor.getCount()==29` (DB isn't empty and contains 29 objects)

The same query works great in othes places of my APP.

I'm testing this on emulated Android 4.4 (api 19) while my app is built with

```
minSdkVersion 12
targetSdkVersion 24
```

Any idea about this strange behaviour ?

Here is the code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static DatabaseHelper getHelper(Context context) {
        if (instance == null)
            synchronized( DatabaseHelper.class ) {
                if( instance==null )
                    instance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
            }

        return instance;
    }

    private DatabaseHelper(Context c) {
        super(c, DB_NAME, null, 6 /* version */);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
        final boolean inTransaction = db.inTransaction();

        if( !inTransaction )
            db.beginTransaction();

        Cursor cur = null;

        try {
//          cur = db.query("sqlite_master", null, null, null, null, null, null); // SAME BEHAVIOUR
            cur = db.rawQuery("select * from sqlite_master", null );

            int count = cur.getCount(); // ASSIGN 29 TO COUNT
            while( cur.moveToNext()) {
                ** NEVER ENTERS HERE **
            }

            if( !inTransaction )
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.e(DBTAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if( cur!=null)
                cur.close();

            if( !inTransaction )
                db.endTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use cursor.moveToFirst(); first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I posted was in a library module. 
When I moved it in the main app module the query on sqlite_master worked!

I upgraded **buildToolsVersion** in build.gradle from 24.0.2 to 24.0.3 in app module and library module. Then a full rebuild.

I don't know why but ... now query works either in main module or in library module!

Answer (score 0):

I just reconstructed your case,and found "sqlite" is reserved for internal use,the following is the ERROR message I got.

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: object name reserved for internal use: sqlite_master

Maybe you can try another table name and see it can work or not.

Comment: I used to query sqlite_master and I never got "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: object name reserved for internal use: sqlite_master". I try to move query in a different place and works!

Comment: This error message can happen only when a new object is created, not with a SELECT.